# AngularJS ng-hide not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Markup looks like:

```
<div id="communication-list" ng-controller="contactListController">
    <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts" ng-controller="contactItemController" ng-dblclick="chatWithUser(contact)" ng-click="contactItemClick($event)">
        <div class="name">{{ contact.username }}</div>
        <ul ng-hide="popoverHide">
            <button ng-click="chatWithUser(contact)">Send Message</button>
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

contactItemController looks like:

```
FF.controller('contactListController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    // Start Text chat
    $scope.chatWithUser = function(currentContact) {
        AppManager.startConversation(currentContact.id);
    }
}
FF.controller('contactItemController', ['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $itemElement) {
    $scope.popoverHide = true;
    $scope.contactItemClick = function(event) {
        console.log('test'); // prints.
        $scope.popoverHide = !$scope.popoverHide;
        event.stopPropagation();
    };
}]);
```

Could there be scope problems? Not sure what is happening. I also tried setting $scope.popoverHide to false just test but no success.

Comment: How to make the HTML less of a mess in this case?

Comment: I compiled my comments into an answer, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you're doing, but there are a few things that can make things easier:

1. Use valid html. Angular manipulates the dom directly. Thus invalid html can lead to hard to debug errors.

   - the outer `div` should probably be an `ul`
   - the inner `div` in `li` could be problematic
   - the innermost `ul` (containing the `button`) is not required (and containing only the button also an error).
2. As you're using nested controllers, use `controller as` to make things clearer.
3. No need to prevent events with angular's click events.

---

Here's a cleaned version of your code:

```js
(function (app, ng) {
  'use strict';

  app.controller('contactListController', [function() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.contacts = [
      { username: 'A' },
      { username: 'B' },
      { username: 'C' }
    ];

    vm.chatWithUser = function chatWithUser(contact) {
      console.log(
        'chatting with', contact
      );
    };
  }]);

   app.controller('contactItemController', [function() {
     var vm = this;

     vm.popoverHide = true;

     vm.contactItemClick = function() {
       vm.popoverHide = !vm.popoverHide;
     };
   }]);

}(angular.module('app', []), angular));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="app">
  <div id="communication-list" data-ng-controller="contactListController as list">
    <ul>
      <li
        data-ng-repeat="contact in list.contacts"

        data-ng-controller="contactItemController as item"
        data-ng-dblclick="list.chatWithUser(contact)"
        data-ng-click="item.contactItemClick()"
      >
        <span class="name">{{ contact.username }}</span>
        <button data-ng-hide="item.popoverHide" data-ng-click="list.chatWithUser(contact)">Send Message</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Place it inside your controller with the scope:

```
FF.controller( 'contactListController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', $element, function( $scope, $rootScope, $itemElement ) 
{
    $scope.chatWithUser = function( currentContact )
    {
        AppManager.startConversation( currentContact.id );
    }

    $scope.popoverHide = true;
    $scope.contactItemClick = function( event )
    {
    console.log('test'); // prints.

    $scope.popoverHide = !$scope.popoverHide;

        event.stopPropagation();
    };
}
```

Comment: What about the `contactItemClick` function ?

Comment: Edited. Everything should be in a single controller. Also addressed the issue on the click event